# How to create a closure signature that passes weak self to inside the closure

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, swift4, swift5

I have created a class called `VerifyObject`, that contains a function with the following signature

```
typealias handlerCodeID = (String) ->Void
typealias handlerCode = (Date, Code) ->Void
typealias handlerError = (NSError) ->Void


class func verifyObject(withID:String?,
  runOnEnter: handlerCode?,
  runOnExit: handlerCode?,
  runOnPause: handlerCodeID?,
  runOnError: handlerError?)
```

when I run these `runOn...` closures, I will have situations where I need to use references to `self` inside the closures, capturing self and creating leaks.

I have read everything I could find about creating `weak self` on swift but the text is so exoteric that I cannot wrap my head around.

I know the objective-c way but that is considered heresy on swift.

How do I create these `typealias` or the function signature or whatever to pass a weak self to inside each of these 4 closures.

Please explain like I am 5 years old. Ok, make it 4.

Thanks.

Comment: You should really prioritize learning about weak/unowned references, and ARC more generally. It's critical to any mid-high level Swift developer.

Comment: Unrelated: if you have a function with that many callbacks, it might be more elegant to instead define a delegate protocol, and take a single instance of that delegate, rather than many ad-hoc closures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `handleCodeID` you can pass `weak self` so you can remove any strong reference cycles.

So when you call `verifyObject(...)` it will be something like...

```
Self.verifyObject(“someString”, { [weak self] date, code in 
//runonenter
},
{ [weak self] date, code in
 //runonexit
 }, 
{ [weak self] string in
 //runonpause
 },
{ [weak self] error in
 //runonerrir
})
```

You can continue this

The typealias doesn’t actually contain this, it’s something you use when calling the specified typealias or any closure

Comment: WHAT???!!! This is brilliant! I though I would like to rewrite the signatures. THANKS